# Is there a package or technique availabe for calculating large factorials in R?

Tags: r, factorial

If I calculate `factorial(100)` then I get an answer of `[1] 9.332622e+157` but when I try to calculate a larger factorial, say `factorial(1000)` I get an answer of `[1] Inf`

Is there a way to use arbitrary precision when calculating factorials such that I can calculate say `factorial(1000000)`?

Comment: `gmp::factorialZ(100000)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For arbitrary precision you can use either `gmp` or `Rmpfr`. For specifically factorial `gmp` offers `factorialZ` and `Rmpfr` has `factorialMpfr`. So you can run something like below

```
> Rmpfr::factorialMpfr(200)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  1246   bits 
[1] 788657867364790503552363213932185062295135977687173263294742533244359449963403342920304284011984623904177212138919638830257642790242637105061926624952829931113462857270763317237396988943922445621451664240254033291864131227428294853277524242407573903240321257405579568660226031904170324062351700858796178922222789623703897374720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> gmp::factorialZ(200)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 788657867364790503552363213932185062295135977687173263294742533244359449963403342920304284011984623904177212138919638830257642790242637105061926624952829931113462857270763317237396988943922445621451664240254033291864131227428294853277524242407573903240321257405579568660226031904170324062351700858796178922222789623703897374720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a web scraper; @Khashaa's answer is probably faster, but I went through for proof of concept and to hone my nascent `rvest` skills:

```
library(rvest)
Factorial<-function(n){
  x<-strsplit(strsplit((html(paste0(
    #%21 is URL speak for !
    "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=",n,"%21")) %>%
      #to understand this part, I recommend going to the site
      #  and doing "Inspect Element" on the decimal representation
      html_nodes("area") %>% html_attr("href")),
    split="[=&]")[[1]][2],split="\\+")[[1]]
  cat(paste0(substr(x[1],1,8), #8 here can be changed to the precision you'd like;
                               #  could also make it match printing options...
             "e+",gsub(".*E","",x[3])))
}

> Factorial(10000)
2.846259e+35659
```

Another possible advantage is using Wolfram's computing power instead of your own (I don't know how efficient the package options are, I imagine they just use asymptotic approximations so this probably isn't a concern, just thought I'd mention it)

Comment: I don't like this very much. While there is value in scraping Alpha for things R doesn;t do ... but it has done factorials for ages.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel certainly not my proudest snippet, and the other answer deserves the tick. Only posting this because I took the time to do it & it's good to have scraping in mind as an option in case you come across something that R can't do easily.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I appreciate the creativity of this answer.  thanks for sharing!